# \ntriangleleft much bigger than \triangleleft

Tags: symbols, amssymb

I need a crossed out `\triangleleft` and found the command `\ntriangleleft`. However, the symbol is much bigger than the symbol produced with `\triangleleft`. Is there a possibility to get the `\ntriangleleft` symbol smaller?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a \triangleleft b \\
a \ntriangleleft b
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\triangleleft` comes from the cm fonts, you can get matching triangles from ams fonts by

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
\begin{align}
a \vartriangleleft b \\
a \ntriangleleft b
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just a stack...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\nottriangleleft{\mathbin{\stackengine{0pt}{\triangleleft}{/}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a \triangleleft b \\
a \nottriangleleft b \\
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `\stackinset`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, stackengine}

\newcommand{\smallntriangleleft}{\mathbin{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{0pt}{/}{\triangleleft}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a\triangleleft b \\
a \smallntriangleleft b
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]